# What is the error on measuring the phase of a sine wave?

Tags: error-analysis, experimental-technique

Let's say I have a wave, with frequency $\omega$ and phase $\phi$, of the form:

$$y(t) = 1 + A  \sin(\omega t+\phi)$$

where $A < 1$. I have measured this wave N times, and we can assume these measurements are evenly spaced over one period. Each of those measurements has an uncertainty in the y-direction of $\sigma_y$, and no uncertainty in the time of measurement (for practical purposes). How well can I measure the phase of this sine wave?

I've tried constructing a Fisher matrix for the problem, but Mathematica thinks it's singular, and I can't see how to invert it either.

Comment: You might be better off taking this to [stats.se]. As a practical matter if you have a fitting package handy you can simply Monte Carlo it. With a fitting package and the data, just ask the fitter.

Comment: Try looking at this: http://www.ingelec.uns.edu.ar/pds2803/Materiales/Articulos/AnalisisFrecuencial/00558515.pdf